# Programmatically detect a Nook tablet

Tags: android, nook, nook-tablet

I know, that i can using the `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER` field of Build object.
But what value must be contain this field for Nook devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and working on Nook Simple Touch Glow (Eink). Caveat: no idea what the HD nooks return.

```
public static boolean isNook()
    {
    String thisManufacturer=android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    Log.d(TAG, "UTIL: Manu: "+thisManufacturer);
    // 'BarnesAndNoble' on Nook Simple Touch with GlowLite

    String thisProduct=android.os.Build.PRODUCT;
    Log.d(TAG, "UTIL: PRODUCT "+thisProduct);
    // 'NOOK' on Nook Simple Touch with GlowLite

    //String thisBrand=android.os.Build.BRAND;
    //Log.d(TAG, "UTIL: Brand "+thisBrand);
    // 'nook' on Nook Simple Touch with GlowLite

    //String thisModel=android.os.Build.MODEL;
    //Log.d(TAG, "UTIL: Model "+thisModel);
    // 'unknown' on Nook Simple Touch with GlowLite

    if( thisManufacturer.equals("BarnesAndNoble") && 
        thisProduct.equals("NOOK"))
        return(true);
    else
        return(false);
    }
```

Comment: I must say that on a UK model of the nook, the Build.MANUFACTURER had the value 'BN LLC' and not 'BarnesAndNoble'. Could be relevant.
I am currently only testing the Build.BRAND, which contains the value 'NOOK', and not the Build.PRODUCT, which contains vaues like 'HD' or 'HDplus'.

Answer (score 1):

`Foxconn` Its better you test on a real device.